# The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>" while trying to parse PageSource from Selenium through getPagesource

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-iedriver

I am generating page source through selenium `getpagesource()` method for firefox and ie browser , but pagesource is not getting parse and message is displayed as:

```
The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>"
```

like "link" tag also shows this message for `meta`,`base`, and `input`

But pagesource generated for chrome is getting parsed.

I am using pagesource file for xpath evaluation which is working for chrome but not for firefox and ie.

Any suggestions or help ?

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".
```

...implies that the clients *GeckoDriver* and *IEDriverServer* is sending some request on which the respective *Browser Client* i.e. **Firefox** and **Internet Explorer** responds back with a **invalid XML**.

Some information about the `request` sent and the `response` received which contains an **invalid XML** could have given us some idea about whats wrong happening.

---

### HTML `<link>` Tag

The [`<link>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp) tag defines a link between a document and an external resource. The `<link>` tag is used to link to external style sheets.

As an example, a link to an external style sheet can be expressed as:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
</head>
```

---

### Conclusion

As a *quick check* ensure that the **`<link>"`** tags are closed properly as per the prevailing [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) and file a defect/bug accordingly.

---

### tl; dr

- [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)